# Simplify Trigonometric Expressions so that they no longer contain specific Trigonometric Ratios

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I want to simplify the following Trigonometric expression so that it no longer contains `Tan[a]` and `Cot[a]`. How can I do that?

`FullSimplify[Tan[a]/(1 - Cot[a]) + Cot[a]/(1 - Tan[a])]` will give me `1 + Cot[a] + Tan[a]`. I want to get rid of `Cot[a]` and `Tan[a]` in the final expression.

Thanks.

Comment: I must be missing something. How do get rid of these? Let `Tan[a]=x`, then the final expression is `1+1/x+x`. What do you mean by get rid of `x` in this? Only when `x=I` or `x=-I` where `I` is `sqrt(-1)` will you get rid of `x`. But `Tan[x]` can never be complex.

Comment: @Nasser Is there any way to force Mathematica to write `1 + Cot[a] + Tan[a]` in form or `Sec[a] and Csc[a]`? That would eliminate `Cot[a]` and `Tan[a]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to force Mathematica to write 1 + Cot[a] + Tan[a] in
>   form or Sec[a] and Csc[a]? That would eliminate Cot[a] and Tan[a]

Yes, if this is what you meant.

```
 ClearAll[a];
 Simplify[TrigReduce[Tan[a]/(1 - Cot[a]) + Cot[a]/(1 - Tan[a])]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The only other way to do in general is like this

```
ClearAll[a, x];
expr = Tan[a]/(1 - Cot[a]) + Cot[a]/(1 - Tan[a]);
expr /. {Tan[x__] :> HoldForm@(Sin[x]/Cos[x]), Cot[x__] :>  HoldForm@(Cos[x]/Sin[x])}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This should work for any expression. But note that if you want to do anything with that expression, then you need to release the hold at that moment.  Using `ReleaseHold[...]`.

As I mentioned in comment, I do not know how this can be done in general. There might be a way to do it using special transformation rules passed to `Simplify`, since `Simplify` in general uses `LeafCount` to simply expressions.

I tried `TransformationFunctions` but could not make it work. I think this is because Mathematica will write `Sin[x]/Cos[x]` back to `Tan[x]` immediately. I am out of my bag of ticks.

Comment: Thanks @Nasser. However, this approach will most probably not work on all expressions that involve `Tan[a]` and `Cot[a]`. I am looking for a general solution that will eliminate `Tan[a]` and `Cot[a]` in every expression that I pass to it.

Comment: I was hoping that Mathematica could somehow turn `1 + Tan[x]` into something like `(Sin[x] + Cos[x])/Cos[x]`. As long as there is no `Tan[x]` and `Cot[x]`. I will be happy. :).

Comment: @RealNoob let me see.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using `Eliminate` but it only works with equations and not expressions. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce to Sin and Cos with ComplexExpand, if you want to pay the price, to have twice the variable in argument.

```
Tan[a] // ComplexExpand

(*    Sin[2 a]/(1 + Cos[2 a])   *)

Tan[a]/(1 - Cot[a]) + Cot[a]/(1 - Tan[a]) // ComplexExpand

(*   Sin[2 a]/((1 + Cos[2 a]) (1 + Sin[2 a]/(-1 + Cos[2 a]))) - 
     Sin[2 a]/((-1 + Cos[2 a]) (1 - Sin[2 a]/(1 + Cos[2 a])))   *)
```

Then simplify to single argument with TrigExpand. But is this realy satisfying?

Answer (score 1):

You have already got several very good answers. Just for the sake of completeness let me give one more

```
g[e_] := 10*Count[e, _Tan || _Cot, Infinity];

FullSimplify[Tan[a]/(1 - Cot[a]) + Cot[a]/(1 - Tan[a]), 
 ComplexityFunction -> g]

(*  1/2 Csc[a] Sec[a] (2 + Sin[2 a])  *)
```

Have fun!